# Computer won't boot, possible causes? Motherboard or CPU

Tags: boot, memory, cpu, motherboard, power-supply

I have a old setup that I haven't used in a while. When I plug it in and turn it on, I see it light up for a second before dying.

So far I have tested the paperclip method with the psu and it works fine. I have also removed all the ram.

My motherboard has a few Leds and a start/reset button (Asus M6E Motherboard). They all light up. I have tried taking out the cpu and putting it back again.

Is it possible my cpu failed or my motherboard failed? I don't have any other 1150 cpu around to check. Since this is one of my old setups, I want to make it to work again, but I'm not sure if I have to buy a motherboard or cpu.

Comment: My motherboard only powers for second so fans don't spin at all.

Comment: See the chart : Power Supply problem.

Comment: Paperclip does not test the psu under load, more than likely psu has died.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I had a PSU around so I have already tested with another PSU.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible reasons here:

Failure or incompatibility.

Most common components that fail are CPU, video card, power supply or a capacitor on the motherboard. If you have any old cpu, you can use it to check is the motherboard OK. If you have any other motherboard for this cpu, you can use it to check is it alright or is this a compatibility issue.

You should leave 1 RAM bank in 1 slot.

Comment: What are the common symptoms of cpu failure? Do I still see a black screen or something?